# What is the best algorithm for counting divisors of a number?

Tags: c, algorithm

I need an optimal algorithm for counting divisors. My algorithm takes lots of time to give me the answers.

Here is the part of my code that counts divisors.

```
int divisor_counter (int n) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (n % j == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you searched for in your favorite search engine? What results did that give you? What problems do you have with possible algorithms that search found for you? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: For starters, the highest number which can divide into `n` except `n` itself is `n / 2`. So you can halve the loop time. Aside: you need to set `counter = 0;`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

here is a function that may help you with that.(you can find it in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/)

```
int divisor(n){
int counter=0;
for(int j=1;j <= sqrt(n);j++) {
            if(n%j==0)//If divisor counts your number
            {
                if(n/j==j)
                    counter++;//Here because quotient is the same as divisor, one counter should be added
                else
                    counter+=2;//Here we should add two divisors; *j*(divisor) and *n/j*(quotient)
            }

        }//End Of for

return counter;//print number of divisors
}
```

> input:12
>
> output:1,2,3,4,6,12

This algorithm is one of the ***optimal*** algorithms which you can use if you have *time limit*.

I suggest you this algorithm because in huge program you may face time problems and find it difficult to handle.

I will explain about this program.In fact, if one of the ***j*** counts your ***number***, you will face two choices:

First, if the ***quotient*** is the same as the ***divisor***, just add ***one*** counter.
Second, if the ***quotient*** is different from the ***divisor***, add two counters;The first one for the ***divisor***, and the second one for the ***quotient***.

Comment: Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discourage as it tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad. Especially if it's just something yourself just found without comments or documentation of any kind.

Comment: j * j <= n would be a better condition that doesn't require the computation of sqrt(n) on EVERY iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: Also you are declaring the counter inside the for-loop but you are returning it outside the function...did you even compile this?

Comment: @Cordelia This is definitely not the best algorithm. It's not even a good algorithm.

Comment: You could at least cache the result of `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: In general, please do not answer invalid questions; it unfortunately encourages others to continue writing bad questions.